# Not able to convert datetime to string in SSIS Expression

Tags: sql-server, string, date, ssis, expression

I am using ssis expression to add a day to a project parameter. Project parameter and out put variable both are string datatype. Please see below code

```
SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30, 1252) DATEADD("dd",1,(DT_DBDATE)@[$Project::Proj_End_Date]), 1, 10)
```

The above is working fine when date passed as "2017-03-10" but it is failing when the Proj_End_Date value is blank. I am getting this below error.

> ### TITLE: Expression Builder
>
> Expression cannot be evaluated.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE%202015&ProdVer=14.0.23107.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.TaskUIFramework.TaskUIFrameworkSR&EvtID=FailToEvaluateExpression&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error code 0x80020005 occurred attempting to convert from data type
> DT_WSTR to data type DT_DBDATE.
>
> Casting expression "@[$Project::Proj_End_Date]" from data type
> "DT_WSTR" to data type "DT_DBDATE" failed with error code 0xC00470C2.
>
> Evaluating function "DATEADD" failed with error code 0xC00470C4.
>
> Casting expression
> "DATEADD("dd",1,(DT_DBDATE)@[$Project::Proj_End_Date])" from data type
> "DT_DBTIMESTAMP" to data type "DT_STR" failed with error code
> 0xC00470C5.
>
> Error code 0x80020005 occurred attempting to convert from data type
> DT_WSTR to data type DT_DBDATE.
>
> Casting expression "@[$Project::Proj_End_Date]" from data type
> "DT_WSTR" to data type "DT_DBDATE" failed with error code 0xC00470C2.
>
> Evaluating function "DATEADD" failed with error code 0xC00470C4.
>
> Casting expression
> "DATEADD("dd",1,(DT_DBDATE)@[$Project::Proj_End_Date])" from data type
> "DT_DBTIMESTAMP" to data type "DT_STR" failed with error code
> 0xC00470C5.
>
> Evaluating function "SUBSTRING" failed with error code 0xC00470C4.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: Why is `Project::Proj_End_Date` a `DT_WSTR` in the first place?

Comment: what should the output be when Project_End_Date is blank?

Comment: Maybe you can just wrap it in a CASE and do something else when Project_End_Date is blank